# DIY Solar lamp circuits with 5252F explained?

Tags: solar-cell

I have a bunch of solar panels, rechargeable batteries, 5252F circuits, inductors and LEDs and while reading https://artists.scitoys.com/three_volts that seems to be enough to make my own solar-powered night lamps. But as a software developer who is a complete Noob at electronics, I want to understand exactly what is going on in that circuit. And I like to know if there are a few more variants to this circuit.
The site is practical but I have various 5V solar panels and not a 2.5V panel. Would they be okay too? And while I understand what inductors do and why the 5252F is needed, I especially need some more understanding on how I can calculate how fast the battery charges and how many microhenries I would need for the various LEDs that I have. (All with different forward voltages.)
So can anyone expand the given explanation here, preferably with some useful formula's?

Comment: The QX5252  operates from 0.9V to 1.5V and is suitable for single AA batteries or single-cell NiMH batteries.  I presume  5252F is the same.

Comment: It probably is. I've ordered https://aliexpress.com/item/QX5252F-QX5252-5252F-TO-92-20PCS/32691752104.html but the drivers don't mention the QX in front of the 5252F. Not sure if there's even any difference between them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct chip name is [QX5252F](https://www.mikrocontroller.net/attachment/158139/QX5252.pdf).

The datasheet of the chip allows up to 6V input, so you can use your 5V panels.

The speed of which the battery will charge is mostly dependent of how much light you would get on your panel.

Unfortunately, the datasheet doesn't provide any information on how the panel are regulated, so to guess, it probably some sort of discrete regulator.

In that case, the voltage of the panels would be at the same voltage as the battery (plus a small dropout voltage of the regulator).

You need then to know the I-V characteristic of the panel to know how much current your panel will provide for this voltage.

Once you know that, you can factor the value for a specific illumination.

To calculate the charge of the battery, it's simply the average current x time - losses.

Comment: That was what I was looking for. As for the panels, I have various different sizes so I'll have some more research on those. But at least I should have enough to make some custom solar lights.